# Iteratively subsetting a dataframe based on part of a column name

Tags: r

My example data.

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("A1", 
"A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A16", "A17", "A2", 
"A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9"), class = "factor"), 
    X_value = 45:61, red_fruit = c(0.45, 0.38, 0.75, 0.9, 0.75, 
    0.86, 0.49, 0.33, 0.38, 0.75, 0.9, 0.75, 0.86, 0.49, 0.33, 
    0.43, 0.24), green_fruit = c(0.75, 0.86, 0.49, 0.33, 0.27, 
    0.38, 0.75, 0.9, 0.75, 0.86, 0.49, 0.33, 0.27, 0.75, 0.86, 
    0.49, 0.33), red_cars = c(0.73, 0.26, 0.65, 0.95, 0.87, 0.15, 
    0.73, 0.26, 0.65, 0.95, 0.87, 0.15, 0.73, 0.26, 0.13, 0.95, 
    0.87), green_cars = c(0.76, 0.98, 0.97, 0.53, 0.27, 0.37, 
    0.12, 0.53, 0.27, 0.37, 0.12, 0.53, 0.27, 0.37, 0.12, 0.45, 
    0.43)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

I'm trying to figure out how to subset a dataframe using the column names. So I have columns that are things like "red_fruit" and another called "green_car". I'm trying to create factors such that the things to the left of the underscore (like "red" and "green") will be their own dataframes. So I'm trying to make a "red" dataframe and a "green" dataframe. So the final dataframe of the "red" dataframe would be something like this

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("A1", 
"A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A16", "A17", "A2", 
"A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9"), class = "factor"), 
    X_value = 45:61, fruit = c(0.45, 0.38, 0.75, 0.9, 0.75, 0.86, 
    0.49, 0.33, 0.38, 0.75, 0.9, 0.75, 0.86, 0.49, 0.33, 0.43, 
    0.24), cars = c(0.73, 0.26, 0.65, 0.95, 0.87, 0.15, 0.73, 
    0.26, 0.65, 0.95, 0.87, 0.15, 0.73, 0.26, 0.13, 0.95, 0.87
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

I can create this red dataframe VERY easily with this snippet below (this code doesn't change column names, but that's easy to implement as well)

```
dfred=df2 %>% 
  select("X_value", starts_with("red"))
```

Same thing could be done to make the green dataframe

My question is whether there is a tidyverse (or non for loop) way to make this happen such that each unique value to the left of the underscore in the column names (such as how "red" and "green" are unique) gets input into the `starts_with()` iteratively and lets me create a nice list with each of the subset dataframes? Someone told me that I should do some kind of regular expression to make this work, but I'm curious if there are other alternatives (or if the regex is easier than I think)?